# How can I recess an electrical outlet that protrudes from a glass mosaic tile wall?

Tags: electrical, walls, tile, receptacle, mosaic

The electrical outlet in my newly installed glass mosaic tile backsplash protrudes. How can I recess it without damaging the glass tile? It is a wall switch that runs to my disposal.

Comment: How far does it protrude?

Comment: And can you see how it is attached?

Comment: Can I recommend that you attach pictures of the outlet with the cover plate in place and removed. If you are unable to attach the pictures due to low reputation then paste in links to them and someone else can come along and in-line your pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is possible to turn off the power, remove the switch, and then cut the nails that are holding the box in place (a recip saw can do this if you are careful). You can then drill holes through the box, push it so that it is flush, and then screw the box back to the stud.

This is fairly finicky work.

Comment: The newer OMTs (oscillating multi tool) with a plunge blade will cut the nails neatly.  Will also cut a bracket that wraps the stud.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely the box itself is recessed and the ears of the outlet is sitting on top of the tile, connected by longish screws.

The solution is to break off the ears and recess as needed.  Spacers may be needed if the box is too deep.  Similarly, a box extender should be used if there is a gap between the wall and the box.

Without plaster ears  [image]

With ears

[image]